# How do i check if a user is accessing a particular module in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I do have a list of `modules` in `D6`.Is there any way by which i could probably find which `module` the `current user` is accessing.If i have a module named `X` and a function named `Y`.If a user is using the `function Y` could i check if the `X module` is being accessed by the user..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7) call to the function in question. Monitor access in-site on the reports page then.

Here is an example:

```
global $user;
watchdog("Access Logging",
         "Access to %func in %file by %user",
         array("%func" => __FUNCTION__,
               "%file" => __FILE__,
               "%user" => $user->name),
         WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
```